# How to edit filters and fields in Odoo 11 that appear in add custom filter option

Tags: filter, odoo-11

I need to change some of the fields in Odoo 11which appear when clicking on Filters/Add Custom Filter. Does anybody have a clue?

Thanks for the help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G5Sq.png)

Comment: Similar answer at [Hide fields in Filters And Group By](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/hide-fields-in-filters-and-group-by-148021)

Answer (score 0):

You can Add/Updated/Delete here  **Settings / Technical / User-defined Filters**

Thanks